# HP Elitebook 8740w starting up

Tags: boot, hardware-failure, temperature

This PC has always run hot, as they do but recently it won't boot up until it's hot. I have to power it up for 5-10 minutes to heat up before it will start. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, the only explanation I can think of is that you have a small crack in a conductor somewhere, and heating up makes both sides dilate and close the gap.

But that makes your PC rather unreliable...